# Error 500 in Symfony when trying to configure FOSFacebookBundle

Tags: facebook, symfony, fosuserbundle

So basically, I'm trying to implement FOSFacebookBundle with FOSUserBundle in Symfony. I followed the readme for the 2.0 branch of FOSFacebookBundle but right now I'm stuck with this error. Any idea ?

The error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to FOS\FacebookBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\FacebookProvider::__construct()
must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface,
instance of FOS\FacebookBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\FacebookProvider given,
called in /var/www/Symfony/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 2434
and defined in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Security/Authentication/Provider/FacebookProvider.php line 37
```

security.yml (security section) :

```
factories:
    - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle/Resources/config/security_factories.xml"

providers:
    chain_provider:
        providers: [fos_userbundle, fos_facebook]
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
    fos_facebook:
        id: fos_facebook.auth 

encoders:
    "FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface": sha512

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:        .*
        fos_facebook:
            provider: fos_facebook 
            app_url: "to_do"
            server_url: "to_do"
            default_target_path: /
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: /admin/.*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /video/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: /$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Relevant parts of config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver:     orm
    firewall_name: main
    use_listener: false
    user_class:   Projectname\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: projectname_user_registration
    service:
        user_manager: projectname_user.my_user_manager

fos_facebook:
    file:   %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/facebook/src/base_facebook.php
    alias:  facebook
    app_id: %projectname_bundle.facebook.app_id%
    secret: %projectname_bundle.facebook.secret%
    cookie: true
    permissions: %projectname_bundle.facebook.perms%
```

MyUserManager.php (modified so I can use the email address as the username with FOSUserbundle. Don't know if it's really relevant, but the error tells me there's a problem with the second argument passed to the FacebookProvider Constructor, and this argument is supposed to be a UserManager):

```
<?php

namespace ProjectName\UserBundle\Model;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class MyUserManager extends UserManager
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->findUserByUsernameOrEmail($username);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('No user with email "%s" was found.', $username));
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **FacebookProvider** (*FOS\FacebookBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\FacebookProvider*) implements **AuthenticationProviderInterface** and not **UserProviderInterface**. It is not a User provider but an Authentication provider, and fos_facebook needs a User provider.

So you should define a **custom User provider** : it's explained [here (Installation step 6. and in "Example Custom User Provider using the FOS\UserBundle")](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/2.0/README.md)

### 1) security.yml

Add this :

```
# application/config/config.yml
security:
    providers:
        ...
        # choose the provider name freely
        my_fos_facebook_provider:
            id: my.facebook.user
        ...
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:      .*
        fos_facebook:
            ...
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
            ...
```

### 2) config.yml

Add this :

```
services:
    my.facebook.user:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Security\User\Provider\FacebookProvider
        arguments:
            facebook: "@fos_facebook.api"
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            validator: "@validator"
            container: "@service_container"
```

### 3) FacebookProvider.php

Create a file FacebookProvider.php in Acme/MyBundle/Security/User/Provider/

Code at the end of [Readme.md](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/2.0/README.md)

### 4) User.php

Edit your User entity by adding some FB-related fields (Id, first name, last name, etc.)

Code at the end of [Readme.md](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/2.0/README.md)